# C# String Format with unknown amount of parameters

Tags: c#, string, parameters, format

Is there any way to create string with dynamic amount of parameters?
For example I've got string like this:

```
var text = "Name: {0}, LastName: {1}, Hobbies: {2}";
Console.WriteLine(System.String.Format(text, "John", "Dohn", "Swimming")
```

And it's working like a charm, but what if somebody can type more hobbies for example from 1 to 10. How to create such a string with dynamic amount of hobbies?

It would be awesome to use something like that:

```
var text = "Name: {0}, LastName: {1}, Hobbies: {2-11}";
Console.WriteLine(System.String.Format(text, "John", "Dohn", "Swimming", "Dancing", "Singing", "Doing nothing")
```

Or some solution like args in functions.

And output should be like "Name: John, LastName: Dohn, Hobbies: Swimming, Dancing, Singing, Doing Nothing". But separator is not important.

Is there any way to handle that in one String Format? Or I need to do some workaround?

Comment: How would that work? What would the output be? `Hobbies: Swimming, Dancing, Singing, Doing nothing`? If so, why? You haven't told it to use a comma as the separator anywhere...

Comment: Use e.g. `string.Format("Name: {0}, LastName: {1}, Hobbies: {2}", "John", "Dohn", string.Join(", ", hobbies))`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend joining the hobbies together with `string.join` before formatting the final string.

```
var hobbies = new[] {"Swimming", "Dancing", "Singing", "Doing nothing"};
var text = "Name: {0}, LastName: {1}, Hobbies: {2}";
Console.WriteLine(System.String.Format(text, "John", "Dohn", string.Join(", ", hobbies)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a method that combines the suggestion from @Conyc with the [params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) keyword to accomplish what you want (in fact, one of the string.Format overloads also uses params).  Here is what that might look like:

```cs
public static string FormatHobbies(string text, string name, string lastName, params string[] hobbies) =>
    string.Format(text, name, lastName, string.Join(", ", hobbies));
```

Sample Input/Output:

```cs
const string text = "Name: {0}, LastName: {1}, Hobbies: {2}";
// output: Name: John, LastName: Smith, Hobbies: 
Console.WriteLine(FormatHobbies(text, "John", "Smith"));
// output: Name: Jane, LastName: Doe, Hobbies: Fishing, Hiking
Console.WriteLine(FormatHobbies(text, "Jane", "Doe", "Fishing", "Hiking"));
```